# PHP Contact form not functioning right

Tags: php, contact-form

For some reason the `$source` variable is causing an issue with my contact form. It continues to throw an error that i should select a source.. Also if i take away the error checker, it's not being included in th email's message.

```
    <!-- HTML -->
    <label for="source" accesskey="H">How did you find us?</label>
    <select name="source" id="source">
        <option value="Google">Google</option>
        <option value="Bing">Bing</option>
        <option value="Yahoo">Yahoo</option>
    </select>


    <?php

      if(!$_POST) exit;

     // Email address verification, do not edit.
     function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+   (ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
    }

    if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

    $name     = $_POST['name'];
    $email    = $_POST['email'];
    $phone   = $_POST['phone'];
    $subject  = $_POST['subject'];
    $source  = $_POST['source'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];
    $verify   = $_POST['verify'];

    if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter your name.</div>';
    exit();
    } else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
    exit();
   } else if(trim($phone) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid phone number.</div>';
    exit();
    } else if(!is_numeric($phone)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Phone number can only contain digits.</div>';
    exit();
    } else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.   </div>';
    exit();
    }

    if(trim($subject) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a subject.</div>';
    exit();
    }else if(trim($source) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a Source.</div>';
    exit();
    }else if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter your message.</div>';
    exit();
    } else if(!isset($verify) || trim($verify) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter the verification number.</div>';
    exit();
    }    else if(trim($verify) != '4') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! The verification number you entered is incorrect.     </div>';
    exit();
      }

     if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
      $comments = stripslashes($comments);
      }


         $address = "example@gmail.com";


        $e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';



       $e_body = "You have been contacted by $name with regards to $subject, their $source additional       message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
        $e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
        $e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email or via phone $phone";

      $msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

      $headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
      $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
      $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
      $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
      $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

      if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

      // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

      echo "<fieldset>";
      echo "<div id='success_page'>";
      echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
      echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
      echo "</div>";
      echo "</fieldset>";

      } else {

        echo 'ERROR!';

      }
```

Comment: Can you post your form code that has the input named source

Comment: @Sean Reposted with input code

Comment: What line is it throwing the error for `$source` by chance? What does it actually say?

Comment: It echoes the if else statement that's set to check if anything wasn't entered/selected. Here's a link: icreatif.com

Comment: Can you post your form code ??

Comment: can you show us print_r($_POST); output ?

Comment: its working fine for me , here is what i got Array
(
    [name] => name
    [email] => mail@gmail.com
    [phone] => 001001001
    [subject] => a Sale
    [source] => Bing
    [comments] => sample comment from bing
)

Comment: you can use FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL instead that long regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this class. I have tested it and it works. If you have any issues, let me know:

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    class Emailer
        {
            protected   $error;
            protected   $printpre;

            // I would personally do jQuery validation instead of custom validation via php
            // If you still want to do your own validation, you may want to modify error
            // handling to include more options. I just did valid or invalid, not into
            // specifics like you've done.
            protected function SanVals($key,$type = 'txt')
                {
                    if(isset($_POST[$key])) {
                            // Strip out html tags
                            if($type == 'txt') {                        
                                    $postval    =   strip_tags($_POST[$key]);
                                    $retval     =   (!empty($postval))? $postval:'';
                                }
                            // Strip out everything but numbers
                            elseif($type == 'tel') {
                                    $postval    =   preg_replace('/[^0-9]/',"",$_POST[$key]);
                                    $retval     =   (!empty($postval) && is_numeric($postval) && strlen($postval) >= 7)? $postval:"";
                                }

                            // Save to error array for reporting
                            if(empty($retval)) {
                                    $this->error[$key]  =   $key;
                                }
                        }

                    return (isset($retval) && !empty($retval))? $retval:"";
                }

            protected   $address;
            protected   $headers;
            protected   $e_subject;
            protected   $msg;
            protected   $name;

            public  function execute($printpre = false)
                {
                    // This just notifies the error reporting to print an
                    //array (for troubleshooting)
                    $this->printpre =   $printpre;
                    // Double check on email set
                    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
                            // Do a filter validation on email
                            if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

                                    if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");
                                    // Basic sanitize / empty check
                                    $sendname   =   $this->SanVals('name');
                                    $email      =   $_POST['email'];
                                    $phone      =   $this->SanVals('phone','tel');
                                    $subject    =   $this->SanVals('subject');
                                    $source     =   $this->SanVals('source');
                                    $comments   =   $this->SanVals('comments');
                                    $verify     =   $this->SanVals('verify');
                                    // If there are any empties, throw errors
                                    if(isset($this->error) && !empty($this->error))
                                        $this->ErrorReport();
                                    else {
                                            if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
                                                $comments = stripslashes($comments);
                                            // Save all necessary values to class globals
                                            $this->name         =   $sendname;
                                            $this->address      =   "test@gmail.com";
                                            $this->e_subject    =   "You've been contacted by ".$this->name;
                                            $e_body             =   "You have been contacted by $name with regards to $subject, their $source additional message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
                                            $e_content          =   $comments.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
                                            $e_reply            =   "You can contact $name via email, $email or via phone $phone";
                                            $this->msg          =   wordwrap($e_body.$e_content.$e_reply, 70);
                                            $this->headers      =   "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
                                            $this->headers      .=  "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
                                            $this->headers      .=  "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
                                            $this->headers      .=  "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
                                            $this->headers      .=  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;
                                            // Send the email method
                                            $this->Send();
                                        }
                                }
                            else {
                                    // If email address is missing, send that back as error
                                    $this->error[]  =   'email';
                                    $this->ErrorReport();
                                }
                        }
                }

            protected   function ErrorReport()
                {
                    $message['name']        =   'Attention! You must enter your name';
                    $message['email']       =   'Attention! Please enter a valid email address';
                    $message['phone']       =   'Attention! Please enter a valid phone number (digits only)';
                    $message['subject']     =   'Attention! Please enter a subject';
                    $message['source']      =   'Attention! Please enter a Source';
                    $message['comments']    =   'Attention! Please enter your message';
                    $message['verify']      =   'Attention! Please enter a valid verification number';

                    if(isset($this->error) && !empty($this->error)) {
                            foreach($this->error as $value) {
                                    if(isset($message[$value]))
                                        $errorSet[] =   '<div class="error_message">'.$message[$value].'</div>';
                                }

                            echo implode("<br />\r\n",$errorSet);

                            if($this->printpre == true || $this->printpre == 1) { ?>
                                    <pre>
                                    <?php print_r($_POST); ?>
                                    <?php print_r($errorSet); ?>
                                    </pre><?php
                                }

                            exit;
                        }
                }

            public  function Send()
                {
                    if(!empty($this->address)) {
                            if(mail($this->address, $this->e_subject, $this->msg, $this->headers)) {
                                    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page. ?>
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div id='success_page'>
                                            <h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>
                                            <p>Thank you <strong><?php echo $this->name; ?></strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset><?php

                                }
                            else { ?>
                            <h2>An unexpected error occurred.</h2>
                            <p>Please contact a system admin</p>
                            <?php
                                }
                        }
                }
        }

        // Initiate emailer
        $emailer    =   new Emailer();

        // Execute with printing error enabled. Turn value from 1 to 0 for no array displays
        $emailer->execute(1);
    }
```